# CSS HTML : my drop down menu li is cutting off an image height

Tags: html, css

learning html/css here. I can't seem to understand how to tweak this drop down menu. I'm trying have to tweak it to hold an image and a name, then to have the links.

Right now the image is getting cut off due to the `<li>` height, when I change the `<li>` height to 100% it get some weird behavior that I don't understand. Any help would be really appreciated to learn whats going on.

image getting cut off

http://jsfiddle.net/FyU89/

odd behavior after I add height: 100%

```
.menu ul li ul li{
padding:0;
float:none;
margin:0 0 0 0px;
width:100%;
height: 100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FyU89/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your css

```
ul.menu-drop li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf4Vj/) link

**Update**:
Upon adding the new css rule you'll find the name disappears from next to the image on Chrome, at least it does for me.  To fix that add a `float: left` on your image and the name will appear next to the image on Chrome, Firefox, and IE; you can then style it more to your liking. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf4Vj/3/) link with the float change.

Answer (score 0):

just going through your css and code, it appears that these drop downs would inherit the height from their parent (.menu), which is set to 30px.  the images seem like they are set to have a height of 48px; this maybe causing your cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css code:

```
ul.menu-drop li {
    height: 50px;
}
```

That sets the height of your list within the menu-drop menu thing so its big enough for the picture.